# Why should we avoid public methods? Benefits of encapsulation

Tags: c#, java, objective-c, oop, scala

Before down-voting let me explain my question. I have a little experience in designing architectures and try to progress. Ones, when I was fixing a bug, I came up with a conclusion that we need to make our `private` method to be `public` and than use it. That was the fastest way to make my job done, and have a bug fixed. I went to my team-leader and said it. After I've got a grimace from him, I was explained that every `public` method is a very expensive *pleasure*. I was told that **every** `public` **method should be supported throughout the lifetime of a project.** And much more..

I was wondering. Indeed! Why it wasn't so clearly when I was looking in the code. It wasn't also so evidently when I designed my own architectures. I remember my thoughts about it:

> Ahh, I will leave this method `public`, who knows, maybe it will come usefull when the system grows.

I was confused, and thought that I made scaleable systems, but in fact got tons of garbage in my interfaces.

**My question**:

How can you explain to yourself if a method is really important and worthy to be `public`? Are any counterexamples for checking it? How you get trained to make `private/public` choise without spending hours in astral?

Comment: Entire books have been written on the nuances of design and refactoring. I don't think SO is appropriate for a question of this scope.

Comment: Besides this question is meaningless. You're never deciding "do I make this method public or private?", what you're trying to achieve is minimal coupling between code modules - i.e. what services do they provide to one another. Any methods that correspond to those services then usually have to be public or in an interface. Forest/trees etc.

Comment: Part off topic, but you may be interested to learn about the [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.71).aspx) modifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you read up on YAGNI http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt

You should write code to suit actual requirements because writing code to suit imagined requirements leads to bloated code which is harder to maintain.

My favourite quote

> Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but
>   when there is nothing left to take away.
>
> -- Antoine de Saint-Exupery French writer (1900 - 1944)

Comment: +1 just for the apt quote, also one of my favorites.

Comment: I get this quote drilled into my head every time I play Civ 4 - on researching Engineering, I think. Also: "Never trust a computer you can't throw out a window."

Comment: YAGNI is BS. It leads to a random walk through the space of possible designs since it rejects the very possibility of foresight and planning.

Comment: @RandallSchulz it doesn doesn't reject foresight and planning, it just rejects prophecy.

Comment: @RandallSchulz YAGNI says you shouldn't implement without a plan to use.  So many projects waste time on features they didn't need or were not used, and those actually used are implemented in ways which were far more complicated than they could have been. http://scienta.no/?p=289 All this leads to a waste of development, but worse, a much higher waste of support time (as much as 3x that in development)

Comment: Wow this is extremly useful topic. I'm very glad you gave it to us.

Answer (score 2):

This question need a deep and thorough discussion on OOP design, but my simple answer is anything with public visibility can be used by other classes. Hence if you're not building method for others to use, do not make it public.

One pitfall of unecessarily making private method public is when other classes did use it, it makes it harder for you to refactor / change the method, you have to maintain the downstream (think if this happen to hundreds of classes)

But nevertheless maybe this discussion will never end. You should spend more time reading OOP design pattern books, it will give you heaps more idea

Answer (score 2):

There are a few questions you can ask yourself about the domain in which the object exists:

- Does this member (method, property, etc.) *need* to be accessed by other objects?
- Do other objects have *any business* accessing this member?

Encapsulation is often referred to as "data hiding" or "hiding members" which I believe leads to a lot of confusion.  Inexperienced developers would rightfully ask, "Why would I want to hide anything from the rest of my code?  If it's there, I should be able to use it.  It's my code after all."

And while I'm not really convinced with the way in which your team leader worded his response, he has a very good point.  When you have too many connection points between your objects, you end up with too many connections.  Objects become more and more tightly coupled and fuse into one big unsupportable mess.

Clearly and strictly maintaining a separation of concerns throughout the architecture can significantly help prevent this.  When you design your objects, think in terms of what their public interfaces would look like.  What kind of outwardly-visible attributes and functionality would they have?  Anything which wouldn't reasonably be expected as part of that functionality shouldn't be public.

For example, consider an object called a `Customer`.  You would reasonably expect some attributes which describe a `Customer`, such as:

- Name
- Address
- Phone Number
- List of orders processed
- etc.

You might also expect some functionality available:

- Process Payment
- Hold all Orders
- etc.

Suppose you also have some technical considerations within that `Customer`.  For example, maybe the methods on the `Customer` object directly access the database via a class-level connection object.  Should that connection object be public?  Well, in the real world, a customer doesn't have a database connection associated with it.  So, clearly, no it should not be public.  It's an internal implementation concern which isn't part of the outwardly-visible interface for a `Customer`.

This is a pretty obvious example, of course, but illustrates the point.  Whenever you expose a public member, you add to the outwardly-visible "contract" of functionality for that object.  What if you need to replace that object with another one which satisfies the same contract?  In the above example, suppose you wanted to create a version of the system which stores data in XML files instead of a database.  If other objects outside of the `Customer` are using its public database connection, that's a problem.  You'd have to change a lot more about the overall design than just the internal implementation of the `Customer`.

As a general rule it's usually best to prefer the strictest member visibilities first and open them up as needed.  Combine that guideline with an approach of thinking of your objects in terms of what real-world entities they represent and what functionality would be visible on those entities and you should be able to determine the correct course of action for any given situation.